# Using # tag in URL to save data from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a site with loads of Javascript, where users input informations, which gets saved in Javascript objects on the site. I also have a working export/import from JSON - once the user fills out the form, he can "Export to JSON", and if he refreshes the page (and the form is cleared), he can "Import from JSON" and the forms get filled.

I want to also **save the data into the URL**, so the users can simply share the URL, and the forms will get **pre-filled based on the URL content**.

Closest **example** I was able to find is these old game calculators - http://classicdb.ch/?talent#Lsoedm0oZVx0f0xoZTMo

The information is encoded in the `#Lsoedm0oZVx0f0xoZTMo` and then processed and the form is filled.

How does one go about implementing this? Can I use the JSON import which I already have?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking how to make the hash that could be part of the URL. This article might help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

In case you want to modify or receive the hash from URL, René's answer answered that already. :)

Comment: Ah, awesome - so I can just take the Javascript object which stores my data (the contents of the forms) and hash it to base64, then append that to the URL, and decode the base64 string (if the URL has one) upon loading back, right?

Comment: I think you'll need to convert the object to string and then hash it, also there is limit 2000 characters for URL, so you should not have longer URL.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind. I will try to hash the JSON, which I can generate already. I will leave the question up for a while longer and then accept your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Appending the hash to the url should not be the question but receiving and processing, right?
For these javascript provides

```
location.hash
```

That way you will get the "Lsoedm0oZVx0f0xoZTMo" and do whatever you have to.

Comment: My question was more about the "do whatever you have to" (i.e. actually saving the data from the forms into <probably> base64), but thank you for pointing me towards this, as it will come in handy!